# How to remove current storage account from Azure Subscription?

Tags: azure

I am learning how to set up AZURE from powershell. So I created a storage account and set it as current storage account and I deleted it from azure but

(Get-AzureSubscription).CurrentStorageAccount still shows the same name though I deleted it from my azure portal

so How to do i remove this from my subscription?

what is the significance of adding it to subscription?

I used Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount "Name"  to set up

to Remove I checked Remove-AzureSubscription But it does not have that option and what is remove azure subscription is for I read the microsoft article but not to able to understand since i am brand new to it..

will this command delete my Azure subscription? if I have all my network and VMs will all get deleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even though the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152906.aspx) for `Set-AzureSubscription` says that you can reset current storage account (using `-ResetCurrentStorageAccount` parameter), I don't think it is implemented yet (at least I could not make it working).

When you call `Set-AzureSubscription` cmdlet, it basically creates an XML file by the name `DefaultSubscriptionData.xml`. This file is stored in `C:\Users\<Your Local Username>\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell` folder. What you could do is edit the file and change the value of `CurrentStorageAccount` node. You would need to reopen PowerShell console for these changes to take effect.

Please note that `Set-AzureSubscription` cmdlet does not impact your server side settings. This cmdlet is basically a convenient way for you to set subscription wide settings so that you don't have to specify them over and over again when you're executing the cmdlet. This is what the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152906.aspx) also states:

> The **Set-AzureSubscription** cmdlet configures common settings including
>   subscription ID, management certificate, and custom endpoints. The
>   settings are stored in a subscription data file in the user’s profile
>   or in a user specified file. Multiple subscription data sets are
>   supported and identified by a subscription name. To select a
>   subscription and make it current, use the **Select-AzureSubscription**
>   cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `Remove-AzureStorageAccount` CmdLet found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205189.aspx

Comment: This will delete the storage account from the subscription which Sam has already done.

Comment: Ah I see, so there is a state issue between powershell and Azure